# Wallpaper change in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, wallpaper

This code works in windows 7, but does not work in the windows 10.
Instead of changing the wallpaper just black screen

```
[DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam,
        string pvParam, uint fWinIni);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, "Image.jpg", 0x0001);
    }
```

Comment: use full path to image. does this work?

Comment: yes helped, thank you very much

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Comment: have you seen the answer? if it worked, accept it as answer

Answer (score 6):

Instead of only passing `Image.jpg`, use the full path:

```
SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, "C:\\Image.jpg", 0x0001);
```